# How to read a file within a Jar with JRuby

Tags: jar, filesystems, jruby

I am working on a Java wrapper for a library I created in JRuby and I can't manage to read a file that is within the JAR.

I have opened the JAR already and the file is there, located on the root folder of the JAR.

However, when I try to run:

```
File.read("myfile.txt")
```

It throws the following error:

```
C:\temp>java -jar c:\libraries\XmlCompare.jar
file:/C:/libraries/XmlCompare.jar!/lib/xmlcompare/app.rb:19:in `initialize': 
No such file or directory - myfile.txt (Errno::ENOENT)
```

I have even tried to make the path absolute (given that the text file is at the root and the ruby source that is executing is inside lib/xmlcompare), by doing:

```
File.read("#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/../../myfile.txt")
```

But then I get:

```
C:\temp>java -jar c:\libraries\XmlCompare.jar
file:/C:/libraries/XmlCompare.jar!/lib/xmlcompare/app.rb:19:in `initialize': 
No such file or directory -
file:/C:/libraries/XmlCompare.jar!/lib/xmlcompare/../../myfile.txt 
(Errno::ENOENT)
```

Any idea on how I can make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Ernest pointed out, this can be done in JRuby the Java way:

```
require 'java'
require 'XmlCompare.jar'

f = java.lang.Object.new
stream = f.java_class.resource_as_stream('/myfile.txt')
br = java.io.BufferedReader.new(java.io.InputStreamReader.new(stream))
while (line = br.read_line())
  puts line
end
br.close()
```

Comment: If this doesn't work, unzip your jar and look at the directory structor.You may need to prepend the jar's name to the `resource_as_stream` method.  For example `...resource_as_stream('/my_jar/myfile.txt')`

Comment: `java.lang.Object.java_class.resource_as_string('/myfile.txt')` should work just the same way

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you read files out of a jar using, for example,  Class.getResourceAsStream(). I don't know JRuby, but I suspect that that's what you're going to have to do, fall back to Java (however that works) and get the InputStream from one of the getResource() calls. A jar entry is *not* accessible as a File in Java, so I wouldn't expect it to be so accessible in JRuby, either.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, I am not so sure that is the case. I think that JRuby has some magic ways to make it work, hence how you can use a Rails application that is full of templates and deploy it using a self-contained WAR to a server. That's what I need to understand.

Answer (score 0):

For me

```
f = java.lang.Object.new
stream = f.java_class.resource_as_stream('/myfile.txt') returned nil.
```

Following way worked fine from ruby

```
stream = self.to_java.get_class.get_class_loader.get_resource_as_stream('myfile.txt')
```

Comment: `self.to_java.get_class.get_class_loader` returns `nil` in jruby-9.0.5.0